# If one character is grappling another, will they be pulled by a third character casting Thorn Whip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, grapple, forced-movement, prone

My Fighter NPC and a Barbarian PC were prone, and the Fighter had the Barbarian grappled. A PC Druid then used [*thorn whip*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thorn-whip) (PHB, p. 282) to pull the Fighter.

Do both the Fighter and Barbarian get pulled? Can the Druid even pull the Fighter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## RAW, the Barbarian does not move.

The *Grappled* condition as specified in the Player's Handbook specifically says that if the grappler is separated from the grappled target, the effect ends:

> The condition also ends if an effect removes the grappled creature from the reach of the grappler or grappling effect, such as when a creature is hurled away by the thunderwave spell.

Since the effect of the Thorn Whip spell is to pull the Fighter closer to the Druid, they are pulled without the barbarian being moved. If the Fighter is pulled out of Grappling range (usually melee range) by this effect, then the Barbarian is no longer grappled. If it does not, then the Fighter simply continues to Grapple them from a different location.

Comment: That assumes that the Barbarian _does_ get separated from the Fighter. What if the Fighter holds on and gets dragged along?

Comment: @MarkWells There are no current rules for "hanging on".  That definitely makes sense, and the DM can make a decision, but as of right now, the only official thing available is that any force movement, to either side, that breaches the reach of the grapple will break it.

Comment: It's a bit circular: the Barb doesn't move because the grapple breaks, because the Fighter moves out of reach, because the Fighter moves and the Barb doesn't. It would be just as correct (and just as circular) to conclude that they both move, because the grapple doesn't break, because they're still in reach, because they both move.

Comment: @MarkWells it is not circular. When someone is pulled (or pushed) it means they failed to hold their ground by any means, including holding onto things to stay still. If the fighter had the chance "hold on" to the barbarian, then he wouldn't be pulled in the first place. In the case of tornwhip, the fighter's chance of holding on coincides with the fighter's chance of being missed. D&D is doing it's job by abstracting all of the above into a single attack roll.

Comment: @MarkWells no, the barbarian doesn't move because nothing causes him to move. The grapple may or may not break, that's unrelated to the Barbarian moving which never happens via forced movement of the grappler in any case.  It's reasonable to assume the grapple is broken because probably the caster wants his or her buddy ungrappled and they probably can cast it to break the grapple as easily as they can cast it to not break the grapple.  Either way the fighter moves, because that's what the spell does,  and the barbarian doesn't, cause that's neither what the spell does not how grappling works.

Comment: @Ruse While I'm sympathetic to the argument that this is baked into the abstraction of the attack roll, Thorn Whip doesn't take the target's strength into account at all. It also doesn't normally make the target drop anything they're holding.

Comment: @MarkWells That's all well and good, but it's not a question of sympathy. The rules are quite clear that people can be moved out of grapple range by forced movement. Thorn Whip forces movement, just like the example of Thunderwave, only in a different direction. There are no unwritten, secret, or conditional rules - there really isn't any room for argument here.

Comment: @T.J.L. The rules are clear that people _can_ be moved out of grapple range by forced movement, but they're not clear on the cases in which that happens. My argument is that it's the cases in which the people involved in the grapple are _forced apart_, which Thunderwave would do, if the target of the grapple cast it.

Comment: @MarkWells The rules neither make nor imply any distinction on the source of the forced movement.

Comment: @T.J.L. The rules don't mention "forced movement". The rule is that when a grappler moves, they can drag or carry the grappled creature with them. This rule makes no exception for forced movement.

Comment: @Mark "The condition also ends if an effect removes the grappled creature from the reach of the grappler or grappling effect, such as when a creature is hurled away by the thunderwave spell." There is no specification as to *which* creature (grappled or grappler) is moved away by the example spell, only that the grappler can no longer reach the grappled.

Comment: A relevant Crawford tweet about a third character pushing a grappler enemy away from a grappled ally: ["Leaving the reach of a grappler does, indeed, end the grapple, as stated in the third bullet of the grappled condition (PH, 290)."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/826218716262068225)